# GIS data not drawing

Tags: gis, netlogo

I'm new to Netlogo and programming in general. To start with, I'm trying to simply load a GIS dataset.

This is my code:

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ countries-dataset ]

to setup
  set countries-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/Users/247214k/Documents/Modelling/Labour-force/data/lga-line.SHP"
end

to display-countries
  gis:set-drawing-color white
  gis:draw countries-dataset 1
end
```

With two buttons - setup and display-countries.

I don't have any code errors, but nothing happens either. Is someone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have assumed the gis extension that is included in the NetLogo 5.2.1 install is working already?

Comment: Please look at how to ask a question on stackoverflow, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I have formatted your code and fixed the title so hopefully you won't get any more downvotes (or I will have, once the edits are approved).

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you for your edits

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just ran your exact code with a different dataset, see below for my exact code. The data I used is the country outlines from [here](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/world/countries_shp.zip). There are four files in the unzipped folder (with extensions dbf, prj, shp, shx). The code works fine.

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ countries-dataset ]

to setup
  set countries-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/countries test/countries.shp"
end

to display-countries
  gis:set-drawing-color white
  gis:draw countries-dataset 1
end
```

I suggest you open your GIS data in a GIS program (eg qGIS) and make sure it is okay. Running 'setup' then 'display-countries' gets me this [image: drawing].

Comment: Thanks for your help @JenB. Can I check to see if any further work is needed to install the GIS extension or is it packaged within netlogo 5.2.1 and should work fine from a straight install?

Comment: It is packaged with netlogo. And if it wasn't installed correctly, you would get an error when you hit the green tick in the code tab. Try with the dataset I used and see if it works for you.

Comment: Open NetLogo's Models Library on the File menu, then open the Code Examples folder, then open the GIS subfolder, and open "GIS General Examples". Press the setup button, then any of the "display..." buttons. If you see a map, the GIS extension is working.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. The GIS general examples works fine for me, but when I use my own code as above with either my own shapefile or the countries.shp nothing happens, I don't get any errors but the polygons don't draw either. Has this happened before? Thanks again.